# Prisma Record Creation With Explicit Many-to-Many Relations

Tags: javascript, mongodb, many-to-many, prisma

How do I create a record in prisma that connects an already created record with an explicit many-to-many relation?  I'm using `mongodb` and below are my models:

```
model RoleOnRoutes {
  id      String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  roleId  String? @db.ObjectId
  role    Role?   @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  routeId String? @db.ObjectId
  route   Route?  @relation(fields: [routeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
}

model RoleOnUserProfiles {
  id            String       @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  roleId        String?      @db.ObjectId
  role          Role?        @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userProfileId String?      @db.ObjectId
  userProfile   UserProfile? @relation(fields: [userProfileId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
}

model Route {
  id    String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  group String
  href  String
  label String
  roles RoleOnRoutes[]
}
```

First, I created a `Role` with:

```js
const role = await prisma.role.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Admin'
  }
});
console.log(role.id) // "657b785c6ff115286115b177"
```

I tried a few different creation data structures for a `Route`, but get an error with each one:

```js
// Unknown argument `where`. Available options are marked with ?.
const route = await prisma.route.create({
  data: {
    group: '',
    href: '/dashboard',
    label: 'Dashboard',
    roles: {
      connect: [
        {
          where: {
            id: "657b785c6ff115286115b177"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```js
// Argument `create` is missing.
const route = await prisma.route.create({
  data: {
    group: '',
    href: '/dashboard',
    label: 'Dashboard',
    roles: {
      connectOrCreate: [
        {
          where: {
            id: "657b785c6ff115286115b177"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```js
// Argument `where` is missing.
const route = await prisma.route.create({
  data: {
    group: "",
    label: "Dashboard",
    href: "/dashboard",
    roles: {
      connectOrCreate: [
        {
          role: {
            where: {
              id: "657b785c6ff115286115b177"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

I had this working when it was an implicit many-to-many relation, but I now want to `Cascade` when one of the records is deleted or updated.